# error in setup for purchase - can't sell app

Tags: android, android-pay, google-play

if someone wants to buy my app he gets following error:

[image]

Since a year the app is online and i never had such an error. I already wrote an email to the Google-Wallet-Team, but they only said that everything is fine with my account. I can't find errors in my program code, also devices with the app can update it normally...
So I really don't know what to do now. Does anyone have a solution for that problem?

Comment: Ensure that 1) Your public key in Google Developer Console and in your app should be identical, 2) You export a signed application package - unsigned package will not work from Google Play, 3) Key must have a minimum expiry date of 2033, 4) Proguard, if you are using it, should have `optimizationpasses` set to 5 - higher values might cause unforseen problems later, and 5) Have you registered with Google Wallet?

Comment: embarrassing...it's the fifth point :D thanks!